# How to add custom click events to dynamic list view?

Tags: android

I have a list view that automatically generates its content from an sql database. I would like specific events to happen to each member of the listview when clicked, based on their content. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You setOnItemClickListener for the ListView

Answer (score 2):

> I would like specific events to happen to each member of the listview when clicked

Set an [`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) on your `ListView`.

> based on their content

Get the item at the current position and handle the event:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Object item = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    if ( /* your condition here */ ) {

    } else if ( /* something else */ ) {

    }
  }
});
```